# Good books on mathematics of information?

Tags: information-theory, cryptography, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence, quantum-information

Are there any good books on the mathematics of information, under whose umbrella would fall
cryptography, information storing, data processing (i.e. data to information), mathematics of artificial intelligence. I understand that many of these topics have originated in computer science, but I want resources on the mathematical foundations of these topics.

Maybe even some mathematics of information as related to quantum computing.

I've also read a little bit of Marcus Hutter's paper 'AIXI' aka 'Universal Artificial Intelligence'.

Comment: This doesn't cover cryptography, but is relevant to AI and the other fields.  Cover & Thomas, *Elements of Information Theory*.

https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Information-Theory-Telecommunications-Processing/dp/0471241954/

Comment: did you see my answer? any reactions/comments?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following make a good start:

1. [Cover and Thomas, Elements of Information Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471241954)

This is at an intermediate mathematical level, but has quite a broad coverage, including more chapters on network information theory in later editions (e.g., ed. 3)

2. [R G Gallager, Information Theory and Reliable Communication](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471290483)

A classic, very mathematical, and still very enjoyable to read. Deeper than Cover and Thomas but narrower. However it does cover some algebraic coding theory which TCover and Thomas doesn't.

3. [D MacKay, Information Theory, Inference and Learning Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521642981)

Quite different than the two above, this focuses more on implementations, and links to learning theory and inference. First to cover LDPC codes in detail [which were invented by Gallager in his PhD thesis in the early 60s]

4. [R E Blahut, Theory of Remote Image Formation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521553733)
5. [R E Blahut, Algebraic Codes for Data Transmission](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521553741)
6. [R E Blahut, Cryptography and Secure Communication](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107014271)
7. [R E Blahut, Principles and Practice of Information Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201107090)

Blahut's books form a nice ensemble, mathematically similar to Cover and Thomas.

8. [R Vershynin, High Dimensional Probability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108415199)

Good for statistics/probability of large data sets.

9. [D G Luenberger, Information Science](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691124183)

Gentler level of mathematics, interesting broad coverage across different applications of information.